# Why is setup.py apparently succeeding installing my package but actually failing to install a dependency?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

below is a terminal session illustrating the problem:

```
$ pip install scrappy --user
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scrappy in /home/louist/Documents/Python/Scrappy
Downloading/unpacking guessit (from scrappy)
  Downloading guessit-0.5.3.tar.gz (45Kb): 45Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package guessit

Downloading/unpacking tvdb-api (from scrappy)
  Downloading tvdb_api-1.8.2.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package tvdb-api

Downloading/unpacking hachoir-metadata (from scrappy)
  Downloading hachoir-metadata-1.3.3.tar.gz (52Kb): 52Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package hachoir-metadata
    Warning: unable to recompile dialog.ui to dialog_ui.py using pyuic4
    (use command "-c egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info --disable-qt" to disable this warning)


Downloading/unpacking hachoir-core (from scrappy)
  Downloading hachoir-core-1.3.3.tar.gz (91Kb): 91Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package hachoir-core

Downloading/unpacking hachoir-parser (from scrappy)
  Downloading hachoir-parser-1.3.4.tar.gz (359Kb): 359Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package hachoir-parser

    warning: no files found matching 'metadata_csv.py'
Installing collected packages: guessit, tvdb-api, hachoir-metadata, hachoir-core, hachoir-parser
  Running setup.py install for guessit

  Running setup.py install for tvdb-api

  Running setup.py install for hachoir-metadata
    Warning: unable to recompile dialog.ui to dialog_ui.py using pyuic4
    (use command "-c install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-3OxvBD-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /home/louist/.virtualenvs/test/include/site/python2.7 --user --disable-qt" to disable this warning)

    changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/hachoir-metadata from 664 to 775
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/hachoir-metadata-gtk from 664 to 775
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/hachoir-metadata-qt from 664 to 775
    deleting hachoir_metadata.egg-info/requires.txt

    changing mode of /home/louist/.local/bin/hachoir-metadata to 775
    changing mode of /home/louist/.local/bin/hachoir-metadata-gtk to 775
    changing mode of /home/louist/.local/bin/hachoir-metadata-qt to 775
  Running setup.py install for hachoir-core

  Running setup.py install for hachoir-parser
    deleting hachoir_parser.egg-info/requires.txt

    warning: no files found matching 'metadata_csv.py'
Successfully installed guessit tvdb-api hachoir-metadata hachoir-core hachoir-parser
Cleaning up...
(test)louist@ltpc:~/Documents/Python/Scrappy$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:51:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scrappy.core as scrappy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "scrappy/core.py", line 10, in <module>
    import guessit
ImportError: No module named guessit
```

In a nutshell, I did the following:

1. start a virtualenv with `mkvirtualenv test`
2. try to install the package i'm developing via `pip install scrappy --user`
3. start python terminal and then try to import `scrappy.core`

Here is my setup.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='Scrappy',
    version="0.2.7 alpha",
    author='Louis Thibault',
    author_email='louist87@gmail.com',
    packages=['scrappy'],
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=['guessit', 'tvdb_api', 'hachoir-metadata', 'hachoir-core', 'hachoir-parser'],
    url='https://github.com/louist87/scrappy',
    license='GPL 3.0',
    description='Rename video files based on information scraped from thetvdb.com',
    keywords=["TVDB", "thetvdb", "rename", "broadcatching", "media"],
    long_description=open('README.rst').read()
)
```

Any ideas as to what's going on?

Comment: Have you tried installing guessit manually?

Comment: @asermax, yes and it works with no issues.  However, I'm trying to distribute this package, so I do need for setuptools to work properly.

Comment: Try running `pip` using absolute path, maybe your system use the wrong `pip`. It should be the one that's installed by virtualenv.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default new virtualenv doesn't include packages installed outside of it (created without `--system-site-packages` option). Therefore your `test` virtualenv doesn't see packages installed to `~/.local` (due to `--user` option).

Either create virtualenv with --system-site-packages option or don't use --user while installing within activated virtualenv.

Comment: This was intended.  I want to make sure that dependencies are automatically resolved by setuptools.  Shouldn't setuptools automatically download the missing pip packages?  It certainly appears to be doing so.  Also, I just noticed that I forgot to add my setup.py file to the question, so I'll do that now.

Comment: @blz: `import` statement in Python doesn't install modules usually. `pip install` as your output shows does download dependencies. *"Either create virtualenv with --system-site-packages option or don't use --user while installing within activated virtualenv."*

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, it was a distros problem
When i installed using the following -

```
sudo apt-get install python-scrapy
```

from command line it work. Do make sure you update your repository before hitting the above command to get a current version

Comment: I'm developing `Scrappy`, not `scrapy`.  Admittedly the name lends itself to some confusion, but note the extra 'p' =)

Comment: @blz - sorry for the misinterpretation !

Comment: no worries!  I should have picked another name for the project precisely for this reason!